# Randomly generating 3-tuples with distinct elements in python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate 3-tuples `(x,y,z)` in python such that no two of `x` , `y` or `z` have the same value. Furthermore , the variables `x` , `y` and `z` can be defined over separate ranges `(0,p)` , `(0,q)` and `(0,r)`. I would like to be able to generate `n` such tuples. One obvious way is to call `random.random()` for each variable and check every time whether `x=y=z` . Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: This is probably the best way. Otherwise you could get into a blocking situation if `p` is big, randomly chooses `0` for `x` and `q` is `1` and cannot choose `0` for `y` any more.

Comment: The ranges as well as x,y,z returned by random() are in floating point so that situation will never arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a generator that yields desired elements, for example:

```
def product_no_repeats(*args):
    for p in itertools.product(*args):
        if len(set(p)) == len(p):
            yield p
```

and apply [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to it:

```
def reservoir(it, k):
    ls = [next(it) for _ in range(k)]
    for i, x in enumerate(it, k + 1):
        j = random.randint(0, i)
        if j < k:
            ls[j] = x
    return ls

xs = range(0, 3)
ys = range(0, 4)
zs = range(0, 5)

size = 4

print reservoir(product_no_repeats(xs, ys, zs), size)
```

Comment: A very nice solution. I have one doubt though - Is this completely on-line or are the tuples generated beforehand by itertools ?

Comment: Tuples are generated in a lazy way, but you still need to enumerate them all.